# Disable Form maximize on double click

Tags: delphi, resize

I want to have a form resize proportionally when the user resizes it. I have done this in the event `OnCanResize` with the following code:

```
NewHeight := Round(Height / Width* NewWidth);
```

To prevent the user maximizing the form by clicking the maximize button I managed to disable it treating the message `WMSysCommand` with the following code :

```
if (AMsg.CmdType = SC_MAXIMIZE) then MessageBeep(0);
```

What I have not managed to do is to prevent maximizing the form when the user double clicks on the title bar. Is there any way to do it in Delphi?

I hope it is clear that I don't want to prevent the user from resizing the form. I just want to prevent resizing when clicking the maximize button and double clicking the title bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As first, remove the workaround you have used in the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message handler and then just remove [`biMaximize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TBorderIcons) option from the [`BorderIcons`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.BorderIcons) property of your form or in other words by setting the `BorderIcons.biMaximize` to False in the Object Inspector, and you'll get maximize button as well as form title double click maximize disabled.

At run-time you could simply use:

```
BorderIcons := BorderIcons - [biMaximize]
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to @TLama's obvious [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15500599/937125):

```
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, 
  GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE) and not WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
```

As opposed to setting `BorderIcons`, this will not force a re-creation of the window handle (no call will be made to `RecreateWnd`). This might be useful when switching/changing your window style dynamically without loosing the window state/handle.